# Getting browserify to work with angular

Tags: angularjs, browserify

My app.js looks like below:

```
//app.js
var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "abc";
});
```

//index.html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{test}}

    <script src="dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
   app/
     index.html
     app.js
     node_modules/
        angular/
```

Angular was installed using npm install.

I then compile the code using the following command:

```
browserify --entry app.js --outfile dist/app.js
```

Then upon opening the file index.html in the browser I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
angular.module('app', []);
```

Further errors:

```
2014-11-30 19:44:46.345app.js:4082 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

What could i be missing ?
.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.

What had to be done is as below:

1. Create a angular-index.js file in node_modules/angular folder
   Contents of this file are as below:

   require('./angular.min.js');
   module.exports = angular;

Then include this file in the browser option of the package.json file.

How exactly this makes things work I am not yet sure.. but this got the code rolling.

Comment: I'm new to this but I'd say it is converting it to an AMD module.

Comment: @Bhargav no, that is not correct, do not change to an AMD module. He is using Browersify which allows the usage of Node modules in the browser

Comment: @runtimeZero so when you install the angular module with npm install, an index.js file is already there, and browserify will find it and read it, simply add require('angular'); at the top of your app.js file